# Not able to view Angular app via express/heroku?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express, heroku

I'm relatively new to express, but I have a single page Angular application that I'm trying to deploy to Heroku here:

https://jabooda-heroku.herokuapp.com/

Unfortunately, it shows up as a blank screen. It does this also when I run my server.js file on port 8000 (though I believe if I can fix it in this instance, it'll fix in Heroku as well). However, when I run 'ng serve -open' in my terminal and view on port 4200, I'm able to see everything just fine. I'm convinced there is an issue with my server.js file which takes care of the routing, but here are all relevant files:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const server = require('http').Server(app);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src'));

server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("App running on port " + port);
})

// PathLocationStrategy

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/src/index.html'));
})
```

**my index.html file** ( takes care of the routing)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jabooda</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

One solution I've seen upon looking this up is to import HashLocationStrategy and LocationStrategy in to my app.module.ts file (snippet below):

**app.module.ts**

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

  providers: [
    ProjectService,
    CareerService,
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
  ],
```

And the routing gets taken care of in the below two files (they are in the same directory), but this did not work, which is why I'm confused now:

**routes.ts**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from '../about/about.component';
import { ProjectsComponent } from '../projects/projects.component';
import { ProjectdetailComponent } from '../projectdetail/projectdetail.component';
import { ProjectDialogComponent } from '../project-dialog/project-dialog.component';
import { SubcontractingComponent } from '../subcontracting/subcontracting.component';
import { CareersComponent } from '../careers/careers.component';
import { ContactusComponent } from '../contactus/contactus.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'about',  component: AboutComponent },
    { path: 'projects',  component: ProjectsComponent },    
    { path: 'projectdetail/:id',  component: ProjectdetailComponent },
    { path: 'project/:id',  component: ProjectDialogComponent },
    { path: 'subcontracting',  component: SubcontractingComponent },
    { path: 'careers',  component: CareersComponent },
    { path: 'contactus',  component: ContactusComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './routes';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

How would I go about doing this? My initial approach by adding the HashLocationStrategy and LocationStrategy providers in to my module file doesn't seem to be working, and I think the server has to be able to make my current routing work but I'm not sure how to approach. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not try to render the src content. Did you try on your local server and it works ? What I always do is that I make a build and use that build to render my render. Your server.js should look like this

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const server = require('http').Server(app);

app.use(express.static(__dirname, 'dist', {index: false}));


server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("App running on port " + port);
})

// PathLocationStrategy

app.get('', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'));
});
```

To build the app here is what I often use to have a better performance

```
ng build --target production --build-optimizer --vendor-chunk --prod --named-chunks false --sourcemaps false --output-hashing all
```

I would recommend you read this post for more understanding of the build options https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: Hey Ulrich -

I tried this and I'm still getting some errors; one in particular: TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: dist.
    
I've seen 'dist' being used, but I don't actually have a 'dist' folder. How exactly does this work?

Comment: Ulrich, I was just able to figure it out using this as a reference: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-disk-serve All I had to do was just run 'ng build --watch' in my terminal and it generated the dist folder for me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh yeah. You have to generate the build. I am updating my answer with a better build options

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your server JavaScript file will render the correct path.

Reference: https://medium.com/@shubhsharma10/how-to-deploy-angular-6-app-to-heroku-52b73ac7a3aa