# Express launching Angular application

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, express, angular6

I have an express server setup online which loads multiple ports and those ports are setup on subdomains for example. port 9000 loads the main domain.com port 8000 loads the main application at "app.domain.com" port 1000 loads "signup.domain.com" and the build version of the app is on port 8500 "build.domain.com".

The application is an Angular application however when I go to load the Angular app it loads on port 4200 or it says 8500 is in use. So currently I am loading that in express like so:

```
// Build Application - In Development
    var appbuild = express();
    appbuild.get('/', function (req, res){
        res.sendFile('/app/build/myapp/src/index.html', { root: '.' })
    });

    var port = 8500;
    appbuild.listen(port);
    console.log('Build App Listening on port', port);
```

So my question is in Express how can I instead of writing sendfile command make it launch the angular app in that location on port 8500 so my subdomain names will work. The reason I'm asking this is because right now all it does is load the index file but angular or the app isn't running so i just see source code that says app-root and a blank white page.

Thank you in advance.
Robert

--- Update. I've decided to post the entire Express file. My issue is trying to load a angular app on port 8500 from the subfolder upon booting of express. Here is the full server.js code:

```
// server.js

const express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    config = require('../config/DB');

    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connect(config.DB).then(
      () => {console.log('Database is connected') },
      err => { console.log('Can not connect to the database'+ err)}
    );   


    // Main Website
    var web = express();
    web.get('/', function (req, res){
        res.sendFile('/web/index.html', { root: '.' })
    });

    var port = 9000;
    web.listen(port);
    console.log('Web Listening on port', port);

    // Main Application
    var app = express();
    app.get('/', function (req, res){
        res.sendFile('/app/index.html', { root: '.' })
    });

    var port = 8000;
    app.listen(port);
    console.log('Main App Listening on port', port);


    // Build Application - In Development
    var appbuild = express();
    appbuild.get('/', function (req, res){
        res.sendFile('/app/build/myapp/src/index.html', { root: '.' })
    });

    var port = 8500;
    appbuild.listen(port);
    console.log('Build App Listening on port', port);

    // Sign up Portal
    var sign = express();
    sign.get('/', function (req, res){
        res.sendFile('/signup/index.html', { root: '.' })
    });

    var port = 10000;
    sign.listen(port);
    console.log('Sign Up Portal Listening on port', port);
```

Comment: Are the JS files served correctly to the front end?

Comment: Which JS files are you referring too? Do you mean the Node_Module files? they were installed using npm and the angular app says it loads when I run ng serve.

Comment: When you build the app, it creates a dist folder which has all the required JS files. Please verify if the JS files that are included in the index.html file are served from the server. Please check the network tab or the developer console if it reports an error.

Comment: If I go into the folder where the app actually is located without starting express and simply build the app using ng serve it says app complied successfully. My issue is when I use express I can't load the app through express. I can point express to a index file located there but the actual angular functionality wont start. If I start everything up using express.

Comment: Thats precisely what I am asking you to check. Though, the index.html is served, are the other files that are required for angular functionality also being served? Try opening the index file after building, there you would find script tags. Please ensure those files are also served correctly. Unless they are served, your app wont work

Comment: Also if I simply load it up locally in VSCode and goto the terminal and the folder angular is and do say ng serve --open the angular app loads up fine. My issue is loading up the angular app on port 8500 when building express. I only seem to be able to point it to a folder but not boot the app..

Comment: how do I do that in the express file to boot it and serve up all the needed files? Is there a way in express to say ng serve port--8500 in this  directory and send file from there.

Comment: If I try to load express after loading the app on that port. express then says the port is already in use. I mean if I manually go in and load the app first within the subfolder. and then load the express server.

Comment: I've updated my question with the full server.js code.

Comment: Please move the discussion to a chat room. Also pls let me know if you were able to identify whether other files were served correctly in, say chrome browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174615/discussion-between-robert-and-ankit-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-backend-express

Update your code to the following:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.listen(8500, () => {
    console.log('Server started!');
    });
```

You need to build the angular app if your angular version not 1.x

```
ng build
```

Also, I think this question is similar to your question:
[Not able to view Angular app via express/heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50310038/not-able-to-view-angular-app-via-express-heroku)

Comment: I rebooted the server to clear the ports started the express server first with the new adjusted code and then in a separate terminal in the app directory i ran ng serve port --8500 and i just get a error saying port 8500 is in use.

Comment: With the above code, your angular build code should run itself on port 8500

Comment: yes this does not work. the angular app does not boot when I load express this way with that code.

Comment: I've updated my question with the full server.js code. If I do what you suggested the app doesn't load and it just ends up loading things on the wrong ports.

Comment: Did you see the link I shared https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50310038/not-able-to-view-angular-app-via-express-heroku

Comment: yeah that didnt help.